# phonegap create new project error

Tags: cmd, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have some problem when I try to create new phonegap project via command prompt.

I followed the steps provided [**here**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

But when I try to create my new project the result is this
[image]

JDK 1.7, apache ant and android SDK are installed in the environment.

Can anyone help me?

i've fix the problem with the cmd, now the problem is that in the res folder,there are 
some errors(god bless the import process via shell), some one can help?

[image]

i replace the files with the cordoba source file(main.xml and strings.xml).
But the big exclamation mark remain on the project folder

the android manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/MercatApp" android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="example" android:label="@string/MercatApp"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Eclipse say for this line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

uses-sdk tag appear after application tag

need help please.

[image]

Comment: Are you using windows and eclipse?

Comment: yes win7 and eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: What are you typing for the create command?

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps to create project

```
     1. Download cordova from phonegap site, extract it.
     2. Create Android project using File > New Project menu in eclipse.
     3. Add cordova.jar from downloaded phonegap folder in libs folder.
     4. Add build path for cordova.jar (Right click libs folder Build Path > Configure build path).
     5. Add xml folder from downloaded phonegap folder to project's res folder.
     6. Add reference of cordova.js in all your html files.
     7. Add necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.
     8. Add following code to your Activity.java file(src > com.yourpackage.com > Activity.java)
     import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
     public class YourActivity extends DroidGap {

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
          }

     }
```

Comment: i have an error when i put your java code in MainActivity.java, eclipse say 'you have an error in your proget' and close the emulator.

Comment: the source of mainactivity.java:

Comment: can you post an example of how will be the java file?

Comment: I your project explorer, I cannot see cordova.jar. I suspect, you have not followed step #3 and #4 as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think You use Phonegap **plugin for eclipse** that is available at **Phonegap tool** directory and you can also download and install from this link [AppLaud] (http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start) 

*using this tool there is no such error what u have  face while creating project.*
@ghost I think u have to try new Phonegap Sdk 3.0 Which is also support Command line project creation and also compile project using command line  on locally or you can build project remotely.